# Rendering Backbone Collection with REST call in View

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I am trying to get a Collection to render in a Backbone View, but it won't populate out the HTML. It will console log after the fetch, but does not console log inside of the _.each. Any clues? I am new to Backbone and am looking for assistance with populating based on REST calls. It works with hard data (inline entries from an array), but seems to trip up on the REST.

```
    <script>
var featuredArticle = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: '',
        headLine: '',
        snippet: '',
        fullStory: '',
        location: '',
        nsfw: '',
        category: '',
        relatedArticleIds: '',
        hasVideoPlaceholder: '',
        numberOfImages: ''
    }
});
var featuredArticles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: featuredArticle,
    url: 'http://myrestendpoint'
});

var articleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var getfeaturedArticles = new featuredArticles();
        getfeaturedArticles.fetch();
        console.log(getfeaturedArticles);
        _.each(that.collection, function (value) {
            console.log(value.headLine);
           $(that.el).append('<li>' + value.headLine + '</li>');
        })

        return that;
    }
});
var articles = new articleView({collection: featuredArticles});
$("body").append(articles.render().el);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating articleView instance, you need to pass an instance of collection not the variable containing the definition.
Hence change :

```
var articles = new articleView({collection: featuredArticles});
```

to

```
var articles = new articleView({collection: new featuredArticles});
```

In articleView's render method, use the collection for fetch. 
Change :

```
var getfeaturedArticles = new featuredArticles();
getfeaturedArticles.fetch();
console.log(getfeaturedArticles);
```

to

```
this.collection.fetch();
console.log(this.collection);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gave me an undefined error when I tried it this way. Any other ideas?

Comment: While accessing members of model, you need to use get method i.e. console.log(value.get('headLine'));

Comment: I tried that, but it fails. I believe the issue is in my fetch.

Comment: An AJAX call like this works:
$.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "http://myajaxcall.com/articles/featured",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.aside, function (index, value) {
                console.log(value.headLine);
            });
        }
                });